# VB.NET Where is the error? System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm new to programming, but i've got an sql error when trying to insert a date to my table.

I've tried converting the date to many formats (yyyy/MM/dd, dd/MM/yyyy, etc) but isn't working either

The program is for controlling monthly payments, so it as an daytimepicker to pick the first payment date and it calculates automatically the others x times (vezes)

My SQL table is:

````
    [Id]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [Date]      DATE          NOT NULL,
    [Vezes]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [Valor]     VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
    [Recebedor] VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
    [Processo]  VARCHAR (150) NULL,
    [Parcela]   INT           NOT NULL,
    [Situação]  BIT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);```


My VB.NET code is:
````

```
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()

        End If
        con.Open()


    Dim dates As Date
    Dim vezes As Double
    Dim valor As String
        Dim recebedor As String
        Dim processo As String
        Dim parcela As Int32
        Dim situacao As Int32

        vezes = TextBox1.Text


    While vezes > 0

            data = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimePicker1.Value)
            valor = "R$" + TextBox3.Text
            recebedor = TextBox2.Text
            If MaskedTextBox3.Text <> "" Then
                processo = TextBox2.Text + "/" = MaskedTextBox3.Text
            Else
                processo = TextBox2.Text
            End If

            parcela = 1
            situacao = 0


        cmd = con.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Pagamentos(date, vezes, valor, recebedor, processo, parcela, situação) values ('" & Dates & "','" & vezes & "','" & valor & "','" & recebedor & "','" & processo & "','" & parcela & "','" & situacao & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            vezes = -1
            parcela = +1

        End While



    Form1.display()
```

Comment: You can use SQL parameters. That way you'd prevent the infamous `SQL Injection`, and the data types would get converted automatically; https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=ado.net%20sql%20parameters

Comment: Don't convert and then there can be no conversion issues. As suggested, use parameters. Only actual strings should be passed as strings.